# How can I convert a date to format "dd/mm" in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the query:

```
select date_open 
from vw_jira_jiraissues@con_jira.cit
where issue_key = 'IBA-1642'
```

How can I convert a date to format "dd/mm" in oracle ?

Comment: You should bookmark the Oracle manual. Things like that can easily be learned by reading it. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions001.htm#autoId5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select to_char(date_open, 'dd/mm') from ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want

```
TO_CHAR(date_open, 'DD/MM')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select to_char(date_open,'dd/mm') date_open from vw_jira_jiraissues@con_jira.cit where issue_key = 'IBA-1642'
```